# how to use footer in html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in HTML and CSS, so I tried to create my site with w3school.
I have used a div with animation but I have a problem that is when I want to write code for the footer, the footer is going back of my Div or left of that.

what is the problem of my div codes?I think the problem is of Positions but I changed them and made a new problem.
please help me

```
<?php
include'connect.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>صفحه اصلی  | زود پروژه</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function function_name() {
myFunction();
    })
function d() {
 var data = "";
        $("p").each(function(){
            data += $(this).text();
        });
        alert(data);
    }

function hide() {
  $('#contact').hide();
}
function myFunction() {
  // Get the snackbar DIV
  var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

  // Add the "show" class to DIV
  x.className = "show";

  // After 3 seconds, remove the show class from DIV
  setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}

</script>


    <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
font-family: "CustomFont";
src: url("iranian.ttf");

}

.parallax { 
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("http://www.themesindustry.com/html/xeone/images/arrow-slide1.jpg");
position: relative;
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 600px; 
text-align: center;

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;

margin: 2px 30px 50px 20px;
  height: 155px;
  border: 3px  #000;

}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);


}


/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front
 {

  background-color: #643094;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back
 {
  background-color:  #00bcd4;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


#snackbar {
  visibility: hidden; /* Hidden by default. Visible on click */
  min-width: 250px; /* Set a default minimum width */
  margin-left: -125px; /* Divide value of min-width by 2 */
  background-color: #840DF0; /* Black background color */
  color: #fff; /* White text color */

  text-align: center; /* Centered text */
  font-size: 22px;
  border-radius: 2px; /* Rounded borders */
  padding: 16px; /* Padding */
  position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the screen */
  z-index: 1; /* Add a z-index if needed */
  left: 50%; /* Center the snackbar */
  bottom: 30px; /* 30px from the bottom */
}

/* Show the snackbar when clicking on a button (class added with JavaScript) */
#snackbar.show {
  visibility: visible; /* Show the snackbar */
  /* Add animation: Take 0.5 seconds to fade in and out the snackbar. 
  However, delay the fade out process for 2.5 seconds */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

/* Animations to fade the snackbar in and out */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1a789a;
  padding-right: 20px;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the "active" element to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #ff8989;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the search box inside the navigation bar */
.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#psen{

    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#pbio{
    font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
padding:1px;
}
.contact{
    font-size: 20px;
}
/* When the screen is less than 600px wide, stack the links and the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

  }
}
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40%;

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
  background-color: #423e3e;
  color: #19d3de;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
}

.caption2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 55%;

  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.caption2 span.border2 {
  background-color: #19d3de;
  color: #000;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;

}

footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <a class="active" href="#home">صفحه اصلی</a>
  <a href="#about">حساب من</a>
  <a href="#contact" id="contact">لیست پروژه ها</a>

</div>
 <div class="parallax">

<div class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="caption">
  <span class="border">زود پروژه</span>

  </div>

</div>
<div class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="caption2">
  <span class="border2">آنلاین پروژه بگیرید یا فریلنسر استخدام کنید</span>

  </div>

</div>
 </div>





 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>


 <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">MyWork</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">MyWork</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">MyWork</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'myBio'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : 18'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>






<!-- The actual snackbar -->
<div id="snackbar"><a href="https://t.me/zoodproject" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;" target="_blank">به زودپروژه خوش آمدید</a></div>




 <footer>sdsd
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your footer is in the correct place (at the bottom of your other content). Where are you expecting it to be?

Comment: if you can run my code . when i change resolution, footer is going up of Div items

Comment: I don't think it's a great idea to head straight into media queries and jQuery when you're new to HTML.

Comment: I took it from a 1500px wide window all the way down to 50px and `sdsd` stayed at the bottom of the page for me

Comment: @MTCoster yes sdsd stay at the bottom and stick. but i want change my code that just when i arrived end of site , can see footer.

Comment: So you want the footer to be hidden until the user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @MTCoster yes  , and another problem is the divs. <div id="divv" onclick="d()" class="flip-card" >
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
<p  style="font-size:20px;padding-top:20px">'.$row['name'].'</p>
<p  style="font-size:15px;padding-top:10px">'.$row['takhasos'].'</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1 id="pp" onclick="d()" style="font-size:13px;padding-top:5px;">'.$row['takhasos'].'</h1> 
      <p style="font-size:10px;" id="pbio">'.$row['bio'].'</p> 
      <p id="psen">سن : '.$row['sen'].'</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></a>

Comment: What are the divs doing now, and what are you expecting them to do?

Comment: @MTCoster i have div like this before snackbar. idont know why dont send my code.so i make this div more and more from mysqli database.  and my problem is that when i have footer, footer is going back of this div

Comment: Can you please add a static demo of that code to your snippet if that’s where the problem is?

Comment: @MTCoster i cant do this because i have to much code. do you have Any Desk for connecting to my pc?

Comment: No one here is going to connect to your PC to help you; this is usually considered a premium service. SO is a community for people to help each other out with specific programming problems. If you can’t reduce your code down to a [mcve], it’s probably not specific enough for the Q&A format here.

Comment: @MTCoster i upload my code completly , please check it and in other resolution. can u find the problem of footer?:(  http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=42939408755323685550

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you are using the `<footer>` element but in your CSS you are referring to the footer ID.

Change `#footer` to `footer` in your CSS.

Comment: thank u , but i dont want my footer stick at the bottom . i want when user arrived end of the page, then can see footer

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

*I will only focus on your question, ignoring the other problems, but the syntax is horribly bad in your code. Make sure you read through the tutorials thoroughly again.*

To get what you want you'll have to put the *flip-cards* inside a div container, like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <!-- All your flip-cards in here  -->
</div>
```

Then use a clearfix hack on the container in CSS , since your cards are using float:

```
#container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

And then also do what I've written below.

---

The `footer` tag in your HTML does not have an id which you are    trying to    reference in your CSS.

- Add an id to your footer or reference to it without the id selector
  (#) in the CSS.

in this case I added the id attribute to the footer tag

```
<footer id="footer">sdsd</footer>
```

As for the CSS, to center the footer at the end of the page. To be seen only when the user reaches the end of the page:

- In your case, just center the text and the HTML normal flow will keep the footer at the end for as long as it's the last displayed element in the body.

  ```
  #footer {
     text-align: center;
  }
  ```

also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: thank u ,but i do this works and when i change resolution, the footer is come up and under the Parallax.

Comment: I've edited the solution to do what you're asking for. But please, go through the HTML, JS and CSS tutorials once more. The code you've provided is a mess.